# npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type "workspace:": workspace:*

Tags: javascript, npm, dependencies, node-modules, yarnpkg

I'm creating a new project with gatsby

`gatsby new YourProjectName2 https://github.com/Vagr9K/gatsby-advanced-starter`

and get an error:

```
info Creating new site from git:
https://github.com/Vagr9K/gatsby-advanced-starter.git

Cloning into 'YourProjectName2'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 420, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (420/420), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (373/373), done.
remote: Total 420 (delta 44), reused 268 (delta 22), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (420/420), 7.74 MiB | 11.79 MiB/s, done.
success Created starter directory layout
info Installing packages...

npm ERR! code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL
npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type "workspace:": workspace:*

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

 ERROR

Command failed with exit code 1: npm install
```

Any idea how I can work around this `npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type "workspace:": workspace:*`?

Comment: Is hitting, https://github.com/Vagr9K/gatsby-advanced-starter/blob/master/package.json#L50 your need npm >=7 https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by using `yarn` instead of `npm`.

Comment: but I need npm to run because other commands depend on npm install. e.g. I need to run npm audit which requires npm install

Comment: Well, in my case removed the 32-bits version of node, and installed the 64-bits. This error is gone after installing 64-bit node js binary.

Comment: This avoids the question which is about npm

Comment: Wouldn't you run pnpm?

Answer (score 44):

I got this error when a project I was working with expected `pnpm` and I was using `npm` instead.

Answer (score 5):

For those who has the similar issue, please check your `package.json` maybe some of your packages using workspace version, especially when you download the lib and play with its nested examples.
Replace the `workspace` with the actual version would help to solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need to check whether the project dependencies version in package.json appear [workspace:*] or not. If u use npm i to install your packages, it will comeout "Unsupported URL Type "workspace:": workspace:*". If u use yarn to install your packages, yarn will ask u which version you want to install.

Answer (score 2):

Downgrading the node version to 16.11.0 worked.

Comment: This is not a solution for the problem. Downgrading version is not a solution, but it will stop users from upgrading and doing any changes.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error before too and I realized that I have tried to install it from the wrong terminal. Maybe you can try to install it from a different terminal and the problem will be solved.

[I tried from ubuntu terminal in vscode and got error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXAW4.png)

[I tried it from Ubuntu on Windows terminal on my computer and it downloaded successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DygaY.png)

Hope it will be useful...

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do `npm install <package_name>` and getting this error. and your project is setup using yarn. Then try running following command.

```
yarn add <package_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I checked my **package.json** I found the following, and removing it solved the problem for me.

```
"nextjs-shared-v13": "workspace:*"
```

**Note: the package name doesn't have to be nextjs-shared-v13**