# Unsupported URL Type "link:" while using NPM

Tags: npm

Following some guidance on the net, I edited my `package.json` to include a `link` URL:

```
...
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "react": "link:../some-other-module/node_modules/react",
}
```

But when installing, I get the following error:

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL
npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type "link:": link:../some-other-module/node_modules/react
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is because `link` has been replaced with `file` in recent versions of NPM. Simply update your `package.json`:

```
...
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "react": "file:../some-other-module/node_modules/react",
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One other reason that we can get a similar error is,

- when a project expects `yarn` and we use `npm` instead.
- or when project expects `pnpm` we use `npm` instead

**Use the appropriate package manager** used in the project.

Source:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/69489832/5384491
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/75174993/5384491
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76998621/5384491

Comment: I got the same error but using proper package manager solved it